# Delete some rows of a column if a value does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['a','a','c','c'],'Value':[1,1,2,2]})
print(d)

    Group   Value
0   a       1
1   a       1
2   c       2
3   c       2
```

Since there is no row with a group of 'b', I want to delete any row with a group of 'a'. I only want to delete the 'a' group because there are no rows in the 'b' group.

I know how to get the number of rows in group 'b' like this:

```
len(d.loc[d['Group']=='b'])
```

and then do this:

```
if len(d.loc[d['Group']=='b'])==0:
    d=d.loc[d['Group']!='a']
print(d)

    Group   Value
2   c       2
3   c       2
```

...but I'm wondering how to work it into the .loc method in one line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more intuitive solution to `len` would be creating a mask and then using `.all`. After that, just reassign to the filtered slice.

```
if ~(d.Group == 'b').all():
     d = d[d.Group != 'a']

d

  Group  Value
2     c      2
3     c      2
```

You can also use a host of other query methods like `df.query` and `df.*loc`.